# Displaying the data of a queue after its deletion

Tags: c, pointers, queue

I'm creating a queue using struct in c to store customers. I'm able to delete a customer node but i would like to display the deleted customer's information i.e name and barcode number

```
typedef struct customer {
char name[50];          // the customer's name
double barcodeNumber;   // the barcode number from the customer's ticket
struct customer *next;  // a pointer to the next customer in the queue after this one
}
Customer;

typedef struct eventQueue {
Customer *head; // points to the customer at the front/head of the queue
Customer *tail; // points to the customer at the end/tail of the queue
} EventQueue;
```

here's my delete function

```
int removeCustomer(EventQueue *qPtr, Customer *c)
{


if(qPtr == NULL)
return INVALID_INPUT_PARAMETER;

if(c == NULL)
return INVALID_INPUT_PARAMETER;

if(qPtr->head == NULL)
return INVALID_QUEUE_OPERATION;


char *name;
double barcode;

strcpy(c->name,name);
barcodeCopy = c->barcode;


c=qPtr->head;
qPtr->head=qPtr->head->next;
free(c);


// Value to be returned if a function is completed successfully
return SUCCESS;
}
```

and here's my implementation of the code

```
void main()
{
printf("\nAttempting to remove customer from queue..");

// (attempt to) remove / pop a customer from the queue
Customer customerInfo;
 // a variable to receive the customer data removed from the queue
result = removeCustomer(pQueue, &customerInfo); // this calls your implementation of removeCustomer()

// if customer wasn't removed successfully
if (result != SUCCESS)
{
    
    printf("ERROR: Unable to remove customer from queue.\n");
}
else
{
    
    printf("..customer removed successfully!\n");

    
    printf("The customer removed was %s who was barcode number %.0lf.\n", customerInfo.name, customerInfo.barcodeNumber);}
```

}

Comment: why not printf after `c=qPtr->head;` ?

Comment: The implementation of the code is in a different file (a tester file) and all test and value display is supposed to be done there

Comment: If I understand correctly , you can only modify the tester file , and not the file with Customer and EventQueue ?

Comment: no, the reverse, I can only modify the removeCustomer file (i.e the 2nd one), the first is a header file I'm not supposed to change and the last is a tester file that I don't need to change. the main code is in the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just decompose the actions in the removeCustomer method

1. Getting the "first/front" customer from the queue

   `Customer* first = qPtr->head;`
2. Copy its data to the Customer info struct you passed as parameter

   `// using first for clarity but qPtr->head->name also works` 
   `strcpy(c->name, first->name);` 
   `c->barcodeNumber =  first->barcodeNumber;`
3. Update the queue - remove front

   `qPtr->head = qPtr->head->next;`
4. Delete the first customer (now extracted)

   `free(first);`

Comment: i was wondering why you are freeing first instead of c. since first is more or less like a temporary struct to store the customer info after deletion

Comment: You have to delete first (actually the content pointed to by first) because it is the memory you dynamically allocated when adding the curstomer to the queue. c points to the customer info variable, allocated on stack (and therefore auto-deleted when out of scope). You use it to retrieve the copy of the first customer in the calling function.

Comment: ok I understand now.thanks